# SharePoint 2013 - redirection when session ends

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint

I created Global.asax file and put it into my web application, which works on SharePoint 2013.
In Global.asax.cs file, I inherited SPHttpApplication class and override 
BeginRequest event. It does not work, the Global.asax file is ignored by SharePoint, or I miss something else to add.
The goal is to create redirection when session expires. What am I doing wrong?
This is my code in code behind:

```
namespace PhoenixHR.Global  
{
    public class PhenixHRHttpApplication : SPHttpApplication
    {
        public override void Init()  
        {      
            try  
            {  
                base.Init();  
                this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Moj_BeginRequest);  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  

            }  
        }

        private void Moj_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
             if (HttpContext.Current.Session["TPL"] == null)   
                Response.Redirect("~/PhoenixHR/start.aspx");  

            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  

            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint"%>
<%@ Application Language="C#" Inherits="PhoenixHR.Global.PhenixHRHttpApplication,PhoenixHR.Global,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=a0bd8fabe3543dc0" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have some exception swallowing in your code can you prove the change is not working? or is it raising an exception every request and just ignoring it?

You will be better off with binding to a different event.  The HttpApplication class has quite a few events you can bind and BeginRequest is very early (first) in the processing of the request pipeline. This will not have access to the Session State.  I would suggest using AcquireRequestState or PostAcquireRequestState.

In order for this to work you will need to create an HttpModule.

```
namespace PhoenixHR.Global
{
    public class SessionMissingRedirectHttpModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private const string LAYOUTS_SUBFOLDER = "/PhoenixHR.Global";
        private const string START_PAGE = "/start.aspx";

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostAcquireRequestState += context_PostAcquireRequestState;
        }

        void context_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get required contexts
            SPHttpApplication application = (SPHttpApplication)sender;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;
            HttpSessionState session = context.Session;

            if (session == null)
                return;

            if (session["TPL"] != null)
                return;

            // get SharePoint context and current SPWeb.
            SPContext sharepointContext = SPContext.GetContext(context);
            SPWeb currentWeb = sharepointContext.Web;

            // build a url to the redirect page.
            string layoutsFolder =
                SPUtility.GetLayoutsFolder(currentWeb);
            string url = string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}{3}", currentWeb.Url, layoutsFolder, LAYOUTS_SUBFOLDER, START_PAGE);

            // prevent redirection loop
            if (context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Equals(url, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return;

            SPUtility.Redirect(url, SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, context);
        }
    }
}
```

To register the HttpModule you will need to edit the web.config of the Web Application that it will run in.

In the /Configuration/system.webServer/modules path add the following

```
<add name="SessionMissingRedirectHttpModule" type="PhoenixHR.Global.SessionMissingRedirectHttpModule, PhoenixHR.Global,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=a0bd8fabe3543dc0" />
```

There are some best guesses for paths to the required application pages so you may need to alter the variables to suit.

Comment: Hi Adam,

Empty try - catch block is only because I do not want to stop execution of this application if exception occure.
When the application is loaded, nothing happens. The event is not executed. Nothing from this file is executed, it does not stops to any break point. Seems, this file is not used or it's ignored by SharePoint.

Comment: The issue is that you code is not going to throw anything unusual in adding an event binding, but it will prevent any exceptions bubbling up correctly.

It would be better practice to check for null references on the objects before using them rather than a blanket try..catch.

Comment: You should be able to add a header to the response to prove if the changes you are making are working.

Place this in the Moj_BeginRequest method

`if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Response != null)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-StackOverFlow", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
`

You can then use a tool like Fiddler or the Development Tools most modern browsers to confirm if the header is present on the response.

Comment: I have done a quick test tonight and you will have to implement an HttpModule to do this. The global.asax will not give you access to the session state most of the time.  I will try and post up a response later as it's late for me and I have an early start tomorrow!

Here is some info on the HttpModules, you may be able to figure out what is needed before I reply.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer to include an example of the HttpModule.  I have built and something similar on my dev farm and it works.